Is this set bounded? A little confusion
Consider the set $$A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x^5 + y^5 < 1\}$$ with the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I have to prove if this set is bounded.
Attempts
I would say the set is superiorly bounded, since the inequality reads $< 1$ hence $1$ is the upper bound.
I would also say that the set is not inferiorly bounded, because I can think of $x, y$ as being both negative and very large, and the inequality would still holds since $x^5 + y^5$, if $x, y < 0$ would be a large negative number.
On the other side, I was also thinking about the fact that there is no superior limit for $x$, if $y$ is chosen accordingly. For example, we just need $y = -10^{120}$ for $x = 10^{120}$ and vice versa.
So: when it's asked to tell if a set is bounded, do I have to consider the boundedness of $x, y$ alone or the boundedness of the region $x^5+y^5$ as a whole?

I’m not sure what exactly is the question. You already pointed out you can make $x$ arbitrarily large by making $y$ arbitrarily large in absolute value but negative, so by definition the set is not bounded.

Note that boundedness of a set does not depend on the topology but rather the metric.

Well, you've answered your own question: any point on the unbounded line $x=-y$ satisfies $x^5+y^5=0<1$.
But in case it's helpful, here's a picture of the region generated by https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyr0Km0LUss0lCvUKhU1-TlKkpNz8zPiy_IyS_RiK6IM9WujDO1MYzV0ajQ0TUy0DEy0NTRqIQxNQFYchFC&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==


Thank you! Sometimes I miss the facts I am stating haha. I need to focus more...

We use the following definition of (un)boundedness.
A set $X\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is bounded if it is contained in some ball $B_\epsilon(x,y)=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R^2}:(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2<\epsilon\}$ for $\epsilon>0$ and of course unbounded if there does not exist such a ball. So to answer your question you have to consider the boundedness of the region which is defined by the inequality $x^5+y^5<1$.
We can show that third quadrant which we will denote by $D_3=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x,y<0\}$ is contained in A. Let $(x,y)\in D_3$, then $x,y<0$. Since 5 is uneven, $x^5$ and $y^5$ are both again negative and $x^5+y^5<1$ (sum of negative numbers is negative). Since we chose $(x,y)$ arbitrarily in the third quadrant this will hold for all of the third quadrant which means $D_3\subset A$ . The third quadrant is unbounded and contained in A which means that A itself must be unbounded
